# fsockopen port checking script

Tags: php, html, fsockopen

I've got a script using PHP and fsockopen to check whether a port is open or closed. It is working some of the time but there are several ports on my IP address I know are open but its returning closed. Anyone have any advice?

```
<?php

  $timeout = "10";

if ( isset($_GET['submit'] ) )
{


        $server  = ($_GET['server']);

        $port   = ($_GET['port']);




      if ($server and $port and $timeout) {
    $verbinding =  @fsockopen("$server", $port,  $timeout);

  }
  if($verbinding) {
    echo "<mark>Port $port is open</mark><br>";
  }
  else {
    echo "<mark>Timed Out: Port $port is closed.</mark><br>";
  }



}
?>
```

The HTML

```
<form method="get" action="">

Server IP/URL:<input type="text" name="server" id="server"  pattern="((^|\.)((25[0-5])|(2[0-4]\d)|(1\d\d)|([1-9]?\d))){4}$"  required><br>

Port Number:<input type="number" name="port" id="port" min="1" max="65535"  required><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe just use one that already exists: http://codehill.com/2012/07/a-simple-port-scanner-in-php/

Comment: That's not the point. Thanks tho.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem because the third parameter of fsockopen is not a timeout parameter. See the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

Comment: I agree with @BrianGottier but you should also use it like `fsockopen($server, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);` so you can read the errors!

Comment: replaced it with  $verbinding =  @fsockopen("$server", $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout); and it still isnt working

Comment: are you reading the errors that are dropping into the `$errno` and `$errstr` fields?

Comment: connection refused. I think my hosting provider must be blocking the ports. When i try it with my website IP and port 80 or 443 it works. I also tried it on WAMP on a local computer and it works for 8.8.8.8:53. I will contact them.

Comment: I think you may encounter that some firewalls can sense if they are being port scanned, or that port scans are taking place, and shut down your connection. If you ever get the chance to check out a hardware firewall, you'll see that the options are amazing. Wouldn't surprise me if your host tells you you're out of luck.